# Using expex across pages

Tags: page-breaking, linguistics, expex

I am using the [`expex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/expex) package to align two types of text, doing it as if it were a gloss, and it works fine. There is one problem, though: Many of the texts I'm working on are longer than a page, and instead of continuing on the next one, which would be desirable, they violate the lower margin, into oblivion. I could just split the text across more than one gloss, but that really is a pain because it forces me to take the appearance and not the logical structure of the document into account. Also, any changes to other aspects of my document's layout force me to reorganize what text goes into what gloss every time.

To sum it all up: I would like to be able to span one gloss across pages using `expex`. Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) No need to add thanks at the end, we like to keep the questions short. If you feel like saying thanks, there is no better way than upvoting and/or accepting an answer.

Comment: I don't think there is any way to do this. For this particular question you might have more luck posting on the [Ling-TeX mailing list](http://heim.ifi.uio.no/~dag/ling-tex.html). John Frampton is on that list and very responsive to questions about ExPex.

Comment: @AlanMunn An answer?

Comment: @egreg I turned the comment into an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just ran across your question.  You should have listened to Alan Munn and posted to the Ling-Tex list.

At present, glosses don't break.  But I think perhaps there is no really strong reason for this.  If you still need this feature, I might be able to add an option to the ExPex package to allow page breaking at the cost of controlling the width of the gloss.  It actually seems to be a good idea.

You can communicate with me directly at j dot frampton at neu dot edu.  I don't get by this website very often.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think there is any way to do this. For this particular question you might have more luck posting on the [Ling-TeX mailing list](http://heim.ifi.uio.no/~dag/ling-tex.html). John Frampton is on that list and very responsive to questions about ExPex.