# Justifying left-to-right text in ExPex free translation with default right-to-left language

Tags: horizontal-alignment, polyglossia, right-to-left, bidi, expex

This question is a follow up to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/356702/justifying-text-within-expex), which asked about justifying all the glosses. The solution worked for justifying `\gla`, `\glb`, and `\glc` but not for `\glft`. The problem is clearly because the default language is Hebrew `\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}`, but I don't know how to get around it.

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{ragged2e}

\usepackage{expex}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{FrankRuehl}
\newfontfamily\englishfont{Corbel}

\begin{document}

\lingset{
    everygla=\Large,
    everyglb=\footnotesize\englishfont,
    everyglc=\footnotesize\englishfont,
    everyglft=\small,
    glftpos=right,
    glwordalign=center,
    glhangindent=0em,
}

\definelingstyle{justified}{
    glrightskip=0pt,glspace=0.5em plus 3em minus 0.15em,
    everyglft=\justifying\noindent
}

\exdisplay[lingstyle=justified]

\begingl
  \gla אאאא בבגגגגב גגגג דדדדדדדד אאאא בבבב גגגג דדדד אאאא בבבב גגגג דדדד אאאאאאאא בבבב גגגג דדדד אאאא בבבב גגגג דדדדדדדד אאאאאאא בבבב גגגג דדדד אאאא בבגגגגבב גגגג דדדדדד //

  \glb aaaa bbbb gggg dddd aaaa bbbb gggg dddd aaaa bbbb gggg dddd aaaa bbbb gggg dddd aaaa bbbb gggg dddd aaaa bbbb gggg dddd aaaa bbbb gggg dddd //

  \glc aaaa bbbb gggg dddd aaaa bbbb gggg dddd aaaa bbbb gggg dddd aaaa bbbb gggg dddd aaaa bbbb gggg dddd aaaa bbbb gggg dddd aaaa bbbb gggg dddd  //

\glft
    \textenglish{Some English text so that you can see whether the hyphenation and justification provided by \LaTeX{} are actually working in this free translation. Some English text so that you can see whether the hyphenation and justification provided by \LaTeX{} are actually working in this free translation.} //
\endgl

\xe

\end{document}
```

**OUTPUT:**
[image]

As you can see, the Hebrew gloss is nicely justified, but the English free translation is ragged left, even though in a fully English environment it comes out fully justified.

Comment: How crucial is it for Hebrew to be the default language and English to be the other language? If you switch those (and put `\hebrewfont` in `\gla`) it works as expected, and the free translation appears on the right of the page instead of the left.

Comment: I tested it by switching the default and other language and then implementing your suggestion, and it doesn't work. It forces the Hebrew text into left-to-right. While the individual words are RTL, then Hebrew text as a whole is LTR. equivalent English the of example an is Here.

Comment: Ah yes, right. And of course surrounding the example with `\begin{hebrew}...\end{hebrew}` (and `\englishfont\setLTR` in English gloss lines) puts you back with the problem you have in your MWE.

Comment: Aside from interlinear and translation environments, though, does it matter whether the default language is Hebrew or English? What is the language of the main body text outside of these special environments?

Comment: The glosses are the main environment in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried a lot of things to get the justification to work in the `\glft` when the example is in a RTL language (either through the document's default language or a `\begin{hebrew}...\end{hebrew}` environment that surrounds the example), but I haven't been successful. I also tried putting it in a side panel following the code in section 12.3 of the `expex` manual, but that didn't help either.

What I would suggest would be to use the `paracol` package rather than `expex` itself to split your translation into a second column. This way your translation column won't be constrained by `expex` at all.

In the example below, I created `interlinear` and `translation` environments that subsume commands from `paracol`, `expex`, and general formatting so that your code can be simpler. I don't have FrankRuehl so I used Ezra SIL for the Hebrew font instead.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{Ezra SIL}
\newfontfamily\englishfont{Corbel}

\usepackage{microtype} % for better automatic spacing in the narrow justified column

\usepackage{expex}

\lingset{
    everygla=\Large,
    everyglb=\footnotesize\englishfont,
    everyglc=\footnotesize\englishfont,
    glwordalign=center,
    glhangindent=0em,
    glrightskip=0pt,
    glspace=0.5em plus 3em minus 0.15em,
}

\usepackage{paracol}

\newenvironment{interlinear}%
    {\begin{leftcolumn*}\begin{hebrew}\exdisplay\begingl}%
    {\endgl\xe\end{hebrew}\end{leftcolumn*}}
\newenvironment{translation}%
    {\begin{rightcolumn}\small\noindent\ignorespaces}%
    {\end{rightcolumn}}

\begin{document}

%   \columnratio{0.6} % 0.6 is the default value for expex's ssratio, so if you want that ratio, uncomment this and adjust as needed
%   \setlength{\columnsep}{3em} % this is the default value for expex's sssep, so if you want that amount of column separation, uncomment this and adjust as needed
\begin{paracol}{2}

\begin{interlinear}
  \gla אאאא בבגגגגב גגגג דדדדדדדד אאאא בבבב גגגג דדדד אאאא בבבב גגגג דדדד אאאאאאאא בבבב גגגג דדדד אאאא בבבב גגגג דדדדדדדד אאאאאאא בבבב גגגג דדדד אאאא בבגגגגבב גגגג דדדדדד //

  \glb aaaa bbbb gggg dddd aaaa bbbb gggg dddd aaaa bbbb gggg dddd aaaa bbbb gggg dddd aaaa bbbb gggg dddd aaaa bbbb gggg dddd aaaa bbbb gggg dddd //

  \glc aaaa bbbb gggg dddd aaaa bbbb gggg dddd aaaa bbbb gggg dddd aaaa bbbb gggg dddd aaaa bbbb gggg dddd aaaa bbbb gggg dddd aaaa bbbb gggg dddd  //
\end{interlinear}

\begin{translation}
    Some English text so that you can see whether the hyphenation and justification provided by \LaTeX{} are actually working in this free translation. Some English text so that you can see whether the hyphenation and justification provided by \LaTeX{} are actually working in this free translation.
\end{translation}

\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much, though the free translation doesn't quite look fully justified.

Comment: It is fully justified, but it has a few overfull `\hbox`es due to the column being so narrow. That's really a separate issue.

Comment: @AML, I just edited the answer to use the default column widths provided by `paracol`, which gives wider columns and shows the justification more clearly. If you want to restore the widths that `expex` uses, uncomment the `\columnratio` and `\setlength\columnsep` lines.

Comment: Thanks again. Finally, how would you modify this to make the top of each column perfectly line up with each other? And furthermore, if you copy/paste the section from `\begin{interlinear}` through `\end{translation}`, to create multiple glosses with free translation, this doesn't work well because they lose "connection" to each other across the pages. Might `\parbox` be a better solution?

Comment: @AML, it seems that `paracol` lines up the baselines of the top line of the `interlinear` and `translation` environments. I'm not a `paracol` user myself so I don't know the best way to change that behavior within the package, but you could ask a separate question.

Comment: The second concern you raise has to do with the fact that `expex` doesn't ever break `\begingl...\endgl` environments across pages (see [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/86001/42880) and [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/255169/42880)). You would have to manually break longer texts into separate `interlinear` environments to allow them to break across pages.

Comment: The column synchronization provided by `paracol` doesn't work by trying to keep the left and right blocks together. Instead, it specifies where each block should start. The 2nd translation is put directly below the point on the page where the 1st interlinear ends (but in the right column). The algorithm tries to put the 2nd interlinear there too (on the left) but there's not enough space, so it goes to the next page.